# Leaflet Draw 0.4.0 - how can I show an error message if polygons intersect?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I’m using Leaflet Draw 0.4.0 and trying to throw an error message to the user when they have drawn 2 polygons that intersect. I though this would be possible by executig the _showErrorTooltip() or _finishShape() functions - both defined in the L.Draw.Polyline class.

The following code snippets are some examples of how the map object is created, and layers are added.

My question is, can I execute the _finishShape() or _showErrorTooltip() functions? And if so how as I don't have access to the correct objects/classes.

```
map = L.map('map').setView([primaryTutorLocation.lat, primaryTutorLocation.lon], 12);

drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(drawnItems);

var newpolygon = L.polygon(newpolyarray, {'noClip': true});
drawnItems.addLayer(newpolygon);
```

Comment: Can you tell us whats in `primaryTutorLocation` and `newpolyarray`? Are you trying to call it on `map`?

Comment: I think this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kyletolle/a06062dcf103167be0ef)  may help you.